# Xamarin Forms Maps con Mvvm

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

Hola amigos estoy tratando de obtener la geolocaliacion de mi telefono con Xamarin.Maps.Forms y Mvvm , pero me sale este error. Entiendo que no puedo convertir el metodo como tal en una position, pero entonces alguien sabe como traerlo de mi view model a mi page.cs ??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{
    private MapPageViewModel _viewModel;
    public MapPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel = new  MapPageViewModel();
    }

    protected  override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        var currentLocation =  _viewModel.GetCurrentLocationCommand;
        EJMap.Pins.Clear();
        Pin Current = new Pin() 
        {
            Position = currentLocation, //aqui esta el error de arriba
        };
       
    }
}
```

Este es mi view model

```
 public class MapPageViewModel
{        
    #region props

        public ICommand GetCurrentLocationCommand { get; set; }
    #endregion
    public MapPageViewModel()
    {
        GetCurrentLocationCommand = new Command(async ()=> await GetCurrentLocationCommandExecute());
    }

    public async Task<Position> GetCurrentLocationCommandExecute() 
    {
        Position currentPosition = new Position();
        CancellationTokenSource cts;
        try
        {
            var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
            if (location != null)
            {
                 currentPosition = new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
            }
            else 
            {
                var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.High, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var currentLocation = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request, cts.Token);

                if (currentLocation != null)
                {
                     currentPosition = new Position(currentLocation.Latitude, currentLocation.Longitude);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        return currentPosition;
    } 
}
```

Comment: currentPosition obtiene algo?

Comment: si lo obtienes podrias enviarlo a traves de un evento, con la clase MessaginCenter, pero podrias usar una propiedad con PropertyChanged se me ocurre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una idea que se me ocurre como te dije en el comentario es usar un evento con la clase `MessaginCenter`, donde te suscribis a un evento y debe haber un receptor y un emisor.

En el constructor de tu `View` podes hacer esto:

```
//variable dentro de tu view.cs
 public string CurrentPosition {get;set;}

  //dentro del constructor para que quede suscripto el evento.
  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string, string>("Mapas", "EnviarPosicion", async (codigo, LectorCodigo) =>
  {
      var currentLocation =  EnviarPosicion;
      EJMap.Pins.Clear();
      Pin Current = new Pin() 
      {
        Position = currentLocation
      };
   });
```

//En tu metodo donde obtenes la posicion realizas el envio mediante el evento.

```
        if (location != null)
        {
             currentPosition = new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
        

          MessagingCenter.Send<string, string>("Mapas", "EnviarPosicion", currentPosition.ToString());
        }
```